# Ionic 5 IonInput maxlength not working for real device android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, ionic-framework, max

In Ionic React maxlength not working for IonInput.Working on browser but not in real device(IOS and android).Try Some solution but not working.

```
  <IonInput
    //name="options"
      type="text"
      value={text}
      onIonChange={(e) =>{ setText(e.detail.value!);console.log(text);}}
      placeholder="OPTION"
      required
      onKeyPress={(e)=>{e.key === "Enter" && e.preventDefault();}}
      enterkeyhint= "enter"
      maxlength={50}
  ></IonInput>
```

Comment: try simple max attribute: `max={10}` and see if it works.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib `max={10}` not working in ionic.

Comment: try maxlength=50